# Passing Primary key "id" all value in URL Parameter : PHP - MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, database, url-parameters

I want to pass my primary key all id value in single url parameter :

*PRODUCT TABLE :*

```
id    -- int 11 , primary key
name  -- varchar
desp  -- varecha
```

table data :

```
    id | name   |   desp 
  ------------------------
    1  |  A     |    f
    2  |  B     |   fg
    3  |  C     |   ghb
    4  |  g     |   bn
```

below code :

```
$sql = "SELECT id from product";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);


while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$id = $myrow['id'];

// echo $id : 1234
}
```

hence i am getting id value but i need to pass this "id" value in single URL PARAMETER:

```
<a href="test.php?test=".$_GET['tes']."&pid=".$id." " >url parameter</a>
```

**note :** i cant keep this anchor link in my while loop , as i want this a single link that will be shown in another  table

*hence my link would be something like :*

```
test.php?test=as&pid=1234
```

but i am unable to get **pid=1234**

hence please let me know how i can get the same

Comment: What's the problem, I don't understand it. The code you present looks fine, expect that you call `$fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` once before your while loop, making it already fetch once! Please share more of your code.

Comment: hey LinkinTED , i have removed that extra fetch : i need to pass " $id = $myrow['id'];" value in my <a href="test.php?test=".$_GET['tes']."&pid=".$id." " >url parameter</a> ... where you see in my anchor link i have define pid=$id ..

Comment: there is a missed semicolon in the second echo statement (the one which echo the anchor tag) in MarkS reply .. just add that semicolon and the code should work correctly

Comment: yes i know " ; " was missed , i did that but still link is not seen

Comment: I commented on MarkS reply and wrote the code so that you can get 1,2,3,4

Comment: hey khaled , i did SELECT CONCAT('',id,',') FROM product ... and i got pid=1,2,3,4, .. hence i am getting extra "," after 4 .. why so... thanks for reply will check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing answer, as I got your idea wrong.

All you have to do is:

```
while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
//.= means that it will connect all values, not override them
$id .= $myrow['id'];

// echo $id : 1234
}
```

THen echo `$id` from anywhere.

Comment: yeah Marks , foreach ($idsArray as $pid){ echo "<a href="test.php?test=".$_GET['tes']."&pid=".$pid." " >url parameter</a>";} ... but link itself got disappear

Comment: There was a mistake in string concatenation, answer edited and should be ok now

Comment: there is a missed semicolon in the second echo statement (the one which echo the anchor tag)

Comment: edit: sorry there was also mistake in `$idsArray[] = $myrow['id'];` . I have forgot `[]` and it was saving only last value.

Comment: i did print_r($idsArray) , and i got my last row value "4".. but i should get "1234"

Comment: check updated comment and code, hope it will be fine now

Comment: hey i was missing " $idsArray[]" , but i am getting 4 link AS :    URL PARMERTER -- FOR VALUE 1 , URL PARMERTER -- FOR VALUE 2 , URL PARMERTER -- FOR VALUE 3 , URL PARMERTER -- FOR VALUE 4 ... also each pid has it own id value ... but i need only one link thats URL PARMERTER -- with all VALUE 1234 means pid=1234 ,

Comment: inshort can i get <a href="test.php?pid='.$idsArray.'" >url parameter</a>

Comment: if it is all you need you were missing single `.` in your code. check changed answer. sorry but i got you idea wrong ;)

Comment: Marks : you know what i did try to put $id but i was not able to get answer ...you know why .. just because of " .=  "  .. i used "=" and echo $id .. great i got my answer..

Comment: bro, one more thing , can i get pid=1,2,3,4  what , i means now i am getting pid=1234 ... but how i can define in " where in " clause , as where in(1,2,3,4)

Comment: @user3209031 update the following statement $id .= $myrow['id']; to be as follows : $id .= $myrow['id'].',' ;  and then $n_id = substr($id,0,strlen($id)-1); then echo $n_id; to see the result

Comment: i did SELECT CONCAT('',id,',') FROM product ... and i got pid=1,2,3,4,  .. hecnce i am getting extra "," after 4

Comment: @user3209031 yes, the query will insert an extra comma ',' but if you use the modified code that I wrote in my previous comment, you will get a new $n_id with 1,2,3,4 and then you can use it directly

Answer (score 0):

declare an array outside the while loop : `$arr = array();` 
then write this statement inside your while loop : `arr[] = $myrow['id'];` this way the array will contain all the IDs and it will increment automatically (you don't have to specify the array index each time). Then you can use that array to get the IDs any time you want. Please if that is not what you want, tell me and explain to me more (because I answered your question based on what I understood so please explain more to me about what you need if it is not the answer). Thanks :)

Comment: i need to pass that $id value in my anchor link ... which is ( anchor link ) outside of while loop

Comment: just use the way that MarkS explained in his reply, but make sure to add the missed semicolon in the second echo statement (the one that echo the anchor tag) and then try to use any value instead of $_GET['tes'] (just for testing) and tell me what you get